# Editing Wordpress Labels

Tags: wordpress

I have a new client who has asked me to make some label changes to an existing WordPress site using the Graphene theme. For instance the "Leave a Reply" text above the comment form.

This language is only found in `ms_MY.po` in the theme files.  This is not a file one can edit from the WP admin.

```
#: loop-author.php:78
#: loop.php:92
msgid "Leave comment"
msgstr "Tulis komen"
```

What I am wondering is if this file is only used at install or whether edits to it now will alter the label text?

Client does not want to provide FTP access and mySQL access is not available.  So before I insist on FTP being set up I wanted to be sure that I could actually effect a change without database access.

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress takes translations directly from .PO/.MO files, you can use poedit or any other tool for PO-file editing.

If you want to change WP-Admin labels so they are usually located at ./wp-content/languages All you need is ftp only to upload edited files to server over existen files.

Don't forget that PO-editors are generate MO-files on save so you need to upload both PO/MO files to the server.